# Unable to render SharePoint lists as iFrame in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, iframe, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I am developing a ReactJS application and trying to embed a SharePoint page using an iframe. However, I encounter the error '*****-my.sharepoint.com refused to connect.' It seems that SharePoint is blocking the embedding due to security restrictions.

below is the code for it

```
import React from "react";


function App() {

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <iframe
        src={"https://*********my.sharepoint.com/personal/*****/Lists/Test/AllItems.aspx?IsDlg=1"}
        width="100%"
        height="900px"
        frameBorder="0"
        allowFullScreen
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[image: ERROR SCREENSHOT]

Is it possible to render a SharePoint page (List) as an iframe in a ReactJS application?

Please help me with that